# Pronunciation of -s after th with Plural Nouns

Tags: pronunciation, singular-vs-plural

I found that rule on one of the sites related to learning English and I would like to know whether the information is correct. The source is not in English so I will try to translate it.
If a noun ending with -th has a long vowel sound or a diphthong before this ending,we have the following changes in the plural:
 [θ] is changed for [ ð], and –s is pronounced like [z]: a path [pɑːθ] – paths [pɑː ðz]; a mouth [mauθ] – mouths [mau ðz].

Is it always true or can we also  use a general rule with such words and pronounce -s voicelessly?

Comment: In thinking about it for a minute or two I couldn't think of any exceptions, but that doesn't mean there aren't any. Note that the pronunciation of the "th" in such words changes in a similar way if you add "ing", as in "mouthing".

Comment: Except many/most native speakers of American English pronounce *clothes* as /kloʊz/ dropping the /θ/ (/ð/)  altogether. Other speakers do say,   or attempt to say, /kloʊðz/. Many just think they're saying that.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pattern that used to exist in many words in English a long time ago. It still occurs with many words in English, but it is not a rule. Some *th*-plurals are almost always pronounced with /ðz/, for example *mouths*. Some are frequently pronounced with either /ðz/ or /θs/, for example *paths* (in British English). Some are nearly always pronounced just like a regular plural with /θs/, for example the word *faiths*.

It won't be considered wrong if you say any of these words with /ðz/, but native speakers will often use  /θs/ for many of these words.

Answer (score 2):

On a list of most frequently used English nouns, I found growth, earth, youth, birth and faith, at least some of which (for me, at least) always (growths, earths [as in 'Astronomers searching for exo-planets have found many Jupiters but no Earths'], births and faiths) or sometimes (/juθs/ or /juðz/) retain the /θ/. I think these are exceptions because they were originally uncountable nouns, and were more lately used countably.

Comment: For me (most-or-less standard Australian English), yes. (I discarded some others.)

Comment: Possibly some people with rhotic accents pronounce 'birth' and 'earth' differently, but as far as I know, 'growth' 'youth' and 'faith' have 'a long vowel sound or a diphthong' (per OP's question).

Comment: Yes, you're right they certainly do! (have long vowels or diphthongs)

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for pronunciation of *s* in plurals *does* apply to these words.

The general is that, if the last phoneme of the noun is voiced, the *s* is also voiced */z/* and if the last phoneme is unvoiced the *s* is also unvoiced */s/*.

What's unusual about words like *path* and *mouth* is not the pronunciation of the *s*, which always follows the general rule, but that the *th* changes from unvoiced */θ/* in the singular to voiced */ð/* in the plural: this in turn causes the *s* to follow the general rule and change to voiced.

You get exactly the same effect with words ending with a long vowel followed by *f*: the unvoiced *f* in the singular becomes a voiced *v* in  the plural. This is better documented because the spelling changes too: *loaf* -> *loaves* and *hoof* -> *hooves*.

Note that in regional accents where the pronunciation of the vowel is different, the outcome may be different. For example, in Yorkshire, Norhern England the *a* in path is pronounced as a short /æ/ as in cat: the *th* therefore remains unvoiced in the plural, and so the *s* also remains unvoiced- */pæθ/* -> */pæθs/*.

Comment: Still, some people say, and even spell it, *roofs*

Comment: Indeed, @AlanCarmack. And this dictionary says that roof is the correct spelling... http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roof